# hmac based request signature for verification

Tags: digital-signature, hmac

say i want an application to integrate my services & need some way of verifying requests from that application, i have an integration key, and a shared secret, i can generate a generate a signature using those values & match it on server side. but for that i need to send integration key along with my request.

but as described here ,https://duo.com/docs/duoweb
this service just passes the signature without integration key, so i am guessing they manually iterate on all integration keys & secrets and generate mac for each of them then compare the signature.

any particular reason for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this service just passes the signature without integration key

It doesn't, although I can forgive you for making that mistake. The function name is a bit misleading.

`sign_request` isn't a particularly accurate description of what it does. It [**MAC**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/32114)s the request (I assume they say "sign" simply because the average developer will have no idea what a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is), but it also includes the request itself in the returned data.

Given:

```
ikey = '3pA0XSAwHBOkyGH43WlZ'
skey = '21FNMyZQ15c4GqTHzUnJUGpYTp35LXieMfxAulY3'
akey = 'rVbrzSNJNBKyspIZgabSt3m8C6zIs20zrJF27t65'
username = 'johndoe'
```

`sign_request` will return:

```
TX|am9obmRvZXwzcEEwWFNBd0hCT2t5R0g0M1dsWnwxNTQ4MzQwNDY0|f8ab99bf117ec109c16b7193b5be7e16238a46f8:APP|am9obmRvZXwzcEEwWFNBd0hCT2t5R0g0M1dsWnwxNTQ4MzQzNzY2|307f27ee3ea75c09c2f2b4e8b3089b49c167b88f
```

Picking that apart:

- `TX` is the hard-coded "`DUO_PREFIX`"
- `am9obmRvZXwzcEEwWFNBd0hCT2t5R0g0M1dsWnwxNTQ4MzQwNDY0` is the base64 encoding of `johndoe|3pA0XSAwHBOkyGH43WlZ|1548340464`, which is `username|ikey|expiration-timestamp` (expiration being 5 minutes from the current time)
- `f8ab99bf117ec109c16b7193b5be7e16238a46f8` is the hex-encoded MAC of `TX|username|ikey|5m-expiration-timestamp` using `skey`
- `APP` is the hard-coded "`APP_PREFIX`"
- `am9obmRvZXwzcEEwWFNBd0hCT2t5R0g0M1dsWnwxNTQ4MzQzNzY2` is the base64 encoding of `johndoe|3pA0XSAwHBOkyGH43WlZ|1548343766`, which is `username|ikey|expiration-timestamp` (expiration being 1 hour from the current time)
- `307f27ee3ea75c09c2f2b4e8b3089b49c167b88f` is the hex-encoded MAC of `APP|username|ikey|1h-expiration-timestamp` using `akey`

So `ikey` is actually included twice in the request.